# php double subtraction from free credit and regular credit?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have a program that needs to be fix. Here is the problem:

For example I have :

Free credit of 2 and regular credit of 5.

For example I want to buy an item for 3 credits.

I want to deduct 2 free credits and 1 regular credits.

so the remaining balance will be 0 free credits and 4 regular credits.

Free credits will be the first to deduct before regular credit deducted.

In my existing program if I buy 1 item for 3 credits

here is the balance come out:
-1 free credits
5 regular credits

Which is not be like that.

I want to have like this:
0 free credits
4 regular credits

I hope someone can help me on this issue.
Thank you.

Comment: Please show (the *relevant* parts of) your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$free_credits -= $cost;
if($free_credits < 0) {
    $regular_credits += $free_credits;
    $free_credits = 0;
}
```

Or preferably in the SQL directly:

```
START TRANSACTION;
    SELECT @ok := (free_credits + regular_credits) > :cost
        FROM user_credits WHERE id = :id  FOR UPDATE;

    IF @ok THEN
        UPDATE user_credits
            SET
                free_credits = free_credits - :cost,
                regular_credits = regular_credits + IF(free_credits < 0, free_credits, 0)
            WHERE id = :id
    ELSE;
        /* something to cause the commit to fail */
    END IF;
COMMIT;
```

As a technicality, for this to work the datatype for free_credits needs to be **signed**.

Comment: So you gain regular credits if you don't have enough free credits? Subtracting a negative adds the number...

Comment: LOL, yeah I guess I was trying to find out what his app will be and sabotage it for my own interests (I've corrected it, thanks)

Comment: The OP might want to test that there are sufficient credits available before undertaking these operations, which will raise concurrency concerns...

Comment: It can be done transactionaly so as to not raise concurency concerns. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if using the select both for calculating the value of @ok and for setting the update lock is valid (or if it has the expected behaviour).